# Сравнить 2 массива и изменить значение первого

Tags: php, массивы

К примеру если [xfields] и [short_link] одинаковые, то взять [id] и присвоить значение ключу [news_id] из другого массива.

**PS: См. скриншот.** В левом массиве может быть несколько [short_link] с одинаковыми значениями и всем им надо присвоить значение числа [id] из правого массива.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода со скриншота:

*Left_Array*

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [news_id] => NULL
        [short_link] => https://site10.ru/sindrom
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [news_id] => NULL
        [short_link] => https://site10.ru/prisoner
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [news_id] => NULL
        [short_link] => https://site10.ru/doljen
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [news_id] => NULL
        [short_link] => https://site10.ru/prisoner
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [news_id] => NULL
        [short_link] => https://site10.ru/prisoner
    )
```

*Right_Array*

```
[0] => Array (
        [id] => 818
        [xfields] => https://site10.ru/gods
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 886
        [xfields] => https://site10.ru/any
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4677
        [xfields] => https://site10.ru/prisoner
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6951
        [xfields] => https://site10.ru/objorstv
    )
```

**Вопрос:** Как сравнить массивы и присвоить значение [id] из Right_Array в [news_id] в Left_Array таким образом, что бы на **выходе был Left_Array** но со значениями [news_id] отличными от NULL ?

Comment: А как звучит собственно вопрос?

Comment: У вас не пример кода, а вывод. Есть ваш код, усилия которые прилагали?

Comment: Это просто SELECT выборка из DB, для постановки вопроса нет смысла в примере запроса.

Comment: Ну так может если это данные из таблиц, то надо `join` организовать?

Comment: Думаю всё не так просто, результат выборки Right_Array_[xfields] я чищу регулярным выражением, что бы приравнять ссылки. Но за подсказку на счёт JOIN спасибо. Возможно придётся создать еще один столбец и в него помещать очищенную ссылку и тогда можно будет воспользоваться джойном. Но а если бы нельзя было создать еще столбец в таблице?

Comment: array_intersect() нашел, проверил ключ на NULL, если да, то array_walk_recursive($array, 'changeID');

function changeID($item, &$key)
{
    if ($key == 'id') $key = 'u_id';
} Можно еще извратиться и перевернуть массив array_flip() чтоб проще было найти и заменить

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ с функцией `array_intersect()` подтолкнул меня к относительно рабочему решению. И если бы массивы были одинаковой длинны, то оно бы работало без ошибок, примерно вот так: `$post_result = [];
foreach($arr_id_not_empty as $key => $post) {
    $intersect = array_intersect($arr_id_empty[$key], $post);
    $news_id = array ( 'news_id'=> $post['id']);
    
    if ( count($intersect) >= 1 ) {
        $post_result = array_merge($intersect, $news_id);
    }
};
var_dump($post_result);`

Answer (score 0):

По сути надо было пройтись по массивам в двух циклах сравнивая строки (если не ошибаюсь что-то типа рекурсии).

То есть, к примеру если в первом массиве 5 элементов, а во втором их 8, то нам надо будет пробежаться по каждому из элементов, что в итоге даст 40 итераций.

Выглядит это в коде примерно так:

```
for( $key_p = 0; $key_p < count($Right_Array); $key_p++ ) {

    for ($key_ch = 0; $key_ch < count($Left_Array); $key_ch++) {

        if ( $Left_Array[$key_ch]['short_link'] ==  $Right_Array[$key_p]['xfields'] ) {
            $Left_Array[$key_ch]['news_id'] = $Right_Array[$key_p]['id']; //* всё ради этого действия! Теперь имеем массив с пронумерованным news_id, если были найдены совпадения
        }
    
    }
};
var_dump($Left_Array); // результат
```